# what's the meaning of scope in the router.ex, is it a newly invented macro?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
  scope "/", HelloWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/hello", HelloController, :index
  end
```

The `scope` is lowercase started, it is a variable or syntax keyword invented macro? How to understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scope`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#scope/2) is indeed a macro, just like `pipe_through`, `get`, `post` etc, as you can see in the documentation.

Under the bonnet it creates the routes to dispatch a matching request to the correct controller action and it creates helper functions to generate links to these routes.

To understand it better, take a look at the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#scope/2) and/or the [code](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.6.11/lib/phoenix/router.ex#L882).

Comment: Thank you for the scope's code hyperlink. It is easy to understood by reading code.

Comment: Just a tip in case you didn't know: A link to the corresponding code can be found in the online documentation next to each function header, it looks like this: `</>`.

Comment: It is very good!